# How do I convert a DatePickerDialog into a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a `Fragment` that requires the user to put in a date. I'm using a `DatePickerDialog` to get that info after a button press, which launches the dialog.  But I was wondering if it was possible to have the `DatePickerDialog` nested within the Fragment, so instead of a button press, the user would just interact with the calendar.  I've managed to build a sample and get it to display using the XML widget, but I have had no luck figuring out how to code it to handle the data. Here is said code:

Here's the dialog:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";
    public static final String EXTRA_DATE = "extraDate";
    private DatePicker mDatePicker;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

        DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.dailog_date, null);

        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_date_picker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, month, day, null);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(view).setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
            }
        }).create();
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date date){
        if(getTargetFragment() == null){
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);

        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a fragment and just treat the DatePicker widget like it was any other type of view by adding a Listener.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


public class DateFragmentTest extends Fragment {

private DatePicker datePicker;

public static DateFragmentTest newInstance(){
    return new DateFragmentTest();
}

public DateFragmentTest(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_test, container , false);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker_widget);
    datePicker.init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Date date = new GregorianCalendar(i, i1, i2).getTime();
            // do something with the date here
        }
    });

    return view;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DatePicker
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/date_picker_widget"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:datePickerMode="spinner"
    android:calendarViewShown="false">
</DatePicker>
```